# Importação e Construção do Plano Amostral Pnad 1999

Tags: r, importação, import

Estou querendo analisar a Pnad de 1999 e expandir seus resultados para população, para isso estou utilizando o pacote `Survey` e , no entanto, o meu problema está na fase de importação e construção do plano amostral.

Nas minhas referências estou tendo problema:

1. Na importação com o pacote `lodown` não estão baixando no `get_catalog` os dados da Pnad 1999, de acordo com http://asdfree.com/pesquisa-nacional-por-amostra-de-domicilios-pnad.html.
2. Nesta referência, o link: `source_url( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajdamico/asdfree/master/Pesquisa%20Nacional%20por%20Amostra%20de%20Domicilios/download%20all%20microdata.R", prompt = FALSE , echo = TRUE )` não está funcionando, que é "Script mestre para cuidar de todas as etapas do download":
   https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/como-ler-pnad-r-jo%C3%A3o-victor-dias/?originalSubdomain=pt

É possivel forçar baixar a Pnad de 1999 no `lodown` e consequentemente aparecer no `get_catalog`?

```
lodown( "pnad" , output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "PNAD" ) )

library(lodown)
# examine all available PNAD microdata files
pnad_cat <-
    get_catalog( "pnad" ,
        output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "PNAD" ) )

# 2011 only
pnad_cat <- subset( pnad_cat , year == 2011 )
# download the microdata to your local computer
pnad_cat <- lodown( "pnad" , pnad_cat )
```